# Turn AnimationDrawable into animation?

Tags: android, animation

I got an AnimationDrawable that is working fine, but to make what I want work, I have to turn it into an Animation instead.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where specifically are you trying to apply this `Animation`?

Comment: This animation is only going to be used to et a set an AnimationListener.

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not possible. There has been a long-standing request to be able to register an `AnimationListener` on an `AnimationDrawable`: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8814  But at the end of the day, `AnimationDrawable` is an image, not an animated effect to be applied to something else, which is why it is not an `Animation`.

Comment: Ok then I have to use a walkaround.